# Portable hard disk with write-protect switch

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, product-rec, write-protect

I'm looking for portable hard disks that have a physical switch (with or without key) to make it "read only" to prevent modification.

Is there a particular keyword I should look for that designate those types of drives, or models I can look into, anything that can guide me will help.

Thanks

Comment: the only physical switches i've seen on portable hard drive cases are the power switches on 3.5" enclosures.  that certainly write-protects them, but it also read-protects them too.  probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: If you're willing to go old school and don't need to store a lot of data, what about a 3.5" floppy? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some very few USB keys can be found [here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=USB+Drive+Write+Protection&x=0&y=0), for example:
[Ritek Ridata Twister 32GB USB Drive with Write Protection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002G9TWUM).
I haven't found any larger write-protected external disks.

For others, this article recommends trafficking the jumpers (!) :
[How to Write-Protect an External Hard Drive](http://www.ehow.com/how_5256821_writeprotect-external-hard-drive.html)

Comment: the article links to a Seagate SCSI drive which apparently had a `WRT PROTECT` jumper setting.  i don't know if that's still common... i mean, unless there was some secret setting i'm not aware of, standard EIDE drives didn't include a `WRT PROTECT` jumper... and my latest SATA-II drive acquisitions don't have any jumpers at all.

Comment: @~quack: True. External disks with write-protect jumpers apparently exist, but might take some doing to find.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a lot of browsing an d was surprised how few drives there are with this feature.
The only drive I've found that is still available is the Chinese [Eaget E901](http://www.eaget.com.cn/en/Products/index_e901.asp). You can still grab this thing from most Hong Kong based resellers.

As for your question about the keyword, the best results came up with the words "write-protect usb". Apart from the drive I mentioned, similar queries turned up plenty of thumb drives but no HDD enclosures (most products are no longer made or sold).

Answer (score 1):

[Read-only USB Stick - Didier Stevens](http://blog.didierstevens.com/2009/12/20/quickpost-read-only-usb-stick)

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's related purchases system led me from the aforementioned Ritek model to the [Kanguru Flashblu 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00190IX40) product line.  I don't have any personal experience with them, but I read through the comments on the various models (2, 4, 8, 16GB).  There were about 10 reviews total.  Bad experiences included:

- one customer said that 5 of the 30 models they ordered arrived with broken switches (the 4GB model)
- another reviewer with a similar (near-)DOA issue, this one for the 2GB model.  The chip apparently came loose from the body of the device within a few days of reception.  The protagonist was able to remedy this with some super glue.
- A couple of people complained about the fact that the cap is not attached to the body of the device.  Personally, I would recommend that these people learn the skill "Glue And String".
- Although no-one complained about the Kanguru's switch itself, someone did mention that the label for it was logically inverted, i.e. the "Read-only" setting was labeled "Read-Write" and vice versa.  "Pen and Sticky Tape" could be beneficial here.

Other than these complaints — gleaned from 3 or 4 different reviews — reviews were overwhelmingly positive; most customers gave their respective model 5/5 stars.

A comment on the Ritek Ridata Twister mentions that it has a relatively awkward-to-use switch: it is apparently a DIP switch that you need a paperclip to operate.  On the upside, it is a 32GB model.